# "Invalid `api_key` value provided" when using steam api

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I want to get the items' price of market by steam api, and I have got a valid from "https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey".

Then I copyed this api key in the following query `https://api.steamapis.com/market/items/731?api_key=xxxxxxxx`, But I always got "Invalid `api_key` value provided".

I also tried 'https://partner.steam-api.com/ISteamEconomy/GetMarketPrices/v1/?appid=754' this api. It seems that no apikey is needed. But there is no document about `appid`. So I still got the wrong answer.

What's wrong here? Could anyone tell me the answer

Answer (score 0):

GetNewsForApp (v0002)
GetNewsForApp returns the latest of a game specified by its appID.

Example URL: `http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=440&count=3&maxlength=300&format=json`

Arguments
`appid` AppID of the game you want the news of.

`count` How many news enties you want to get returned.

`maxlength` Maximum length of each news entry.

`format` Output format. `json` (default), `xml` or `vdf`.